# Javascript errors caused by <script> elements being wrapped inside a <strong> tag

Tags: theming, 8

I noticed that my site footer and a lot of `<script>` elements are wrapped inside a `<strong>` tag.

This is causing a lot of JS errors of the type:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissionsHash' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'StateModel' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'AuralView' of undefined

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the checkbox 'Trim this field to a maximum number of characters' was checked in one of my views which was trimming some HTML from the field content (closing tags) and causing the issue.

checking the option 'Field can contain HTML' fixed the issue for me.

[image]